# Reversing the Data

Tags: php, html

All I hope you are doing fine. Ummmm I'm working on a chat room and the problem I'm facing is that, when the page loads it shows the first message, I am thinking of how to make it show the last/new message when the page loads....
Here is my code that shows the data:

```
    </div>


<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-light-grey w3-bar-block" style="width:83.6%;height:75.4%">
  <h3 class="w3-bar-item">Menu</h3>
  <div id="display"></div>
</div>
<div class="w3-sidebar w3-light-grey w3-bar-block" style="width:16.5%;height:75.4%;margin-left:1140px;">
  <h3 class="w3-bar-item">Menu</h3>
  <div>
  <h1>asdasd</h1>
   <h1>asdasd</h1>
    <h1>asdasd</h1>
     <h1>asdasd</h1>
      <h1>asdasd</h1>
       <h1>asdasd</h1>
        <h1>asdasd</h1>
         <h1>asdasd</h1>
          <h1>asdasd</h1>
           <h1>asdasd</h1>
            <h1>asdasd</h1>
             <h1>asdasd</h1>
              <h1>asdasd</h1>
               <h1>asdasd</h1>
                <h1>asdasd</h1>
                 <h1>asdasd</h1>
                  <h1>asdasd</h1>
                  </div>
</div>
        <script>

                setInterval(function(){
            $('#display').load("pages/get.php").fadeIn("slow");
        }, 1000);

        </script>
```

get.php :

```
<?php
require('../system/db.php');
global $con;
$get = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM zadx_chat ORDER BY id");
if(mysqli_num_rows($get) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get)){
        echo "<p>" . $row['message'] . "</p>";
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: There is not enough information. We would have to see the contents of `get.php` which is loading the messages.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Accordingly, this has nothing to do with CSS. It's all about how the data is derived.

Comment: @Chloe edited and added get.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to

```
$get = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM zadx_chat ORDER BY created_at desc");
```

You will need to ensure `created_at` is a datetime field. You can also use `order by id desc` for simple databases.

Answer (score 0):

Check your page.php and in that if there is query to get messages make sure to change that query to Descending order. Like if there is ORDER BY table_column ASC then change it to ORDER by table_column DESC. That should do job for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **insertAfter** function of jquery to set the data in the html page and set the id for the div which contains the  tags list

```
<div id='starting_div'>
<h1>asdasd</h1>
<h1>asdasd</h1>
<h1>asdasd</h1>
<h1>asdasd</h1>
<h1>asdasd</h1>
</div>


$(your_dynamic_data).insertAfter('#starting_div');
```

Comment: No brother its not about the list.. its about the messages